# Group by newly created column in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by

I have created a column conditional on another column `TYPE`. -1 when `TYPE`=`IN`, 1 when `TYPE`=`OUT`.

```
SELECT *, 
  CASE TYPE
     WHEN 'IN' THEN -1 
     WHEN 'OUT' THEN 1
  END AS TYPE_NUMERIC

FROM `SALES_TABLE`
```

Table looks as below:

```
ID     DATE         TYPE      QTY  

X100   2010-11-02   IN        1000
X100   2010-11-02   OUT       1000
X100   2010-11-02   OUT       1000
X100   2010-11-02   IN        1000
X100   2010-11-04   IN        1000
       ...
```

How do I group the data by `ID` and `QTY`, then sum `TYPE_NUMERIC`, select the **earliest** `Date`, **count** number of rows in each group?

Using the sample table above as an example, expected output should look something like this:

```
ID     QTY    SUM_TYPE_NUMERIC  first_DATE         TYPE      count_rows

X100   1000   0                 2010-11-02         IN        4
X100   1000   -1                2010-11-04         IN        1
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can a given date have more than one IN or OUT?

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, yes that's possible

Comment: Then add sample data which reflects the actual problem.

Comment: Just added more sample data @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    `ID`,
    `QTY`,
    SUM(IF(`TYPE` = 'IN', -1, IF(`TYPE` = 'OUT', 1, 0))) AS SUM_TYPE_NUMERIC,
    MIN(`DATE`) AS first_DATE,
    COUNT(*) AS count_rows
FROM `SALES_TABLE`
GROUP BY `ID`, `QTY`
```

Alternatives if you can't use IF() statement:

**A- Store directly -1 and 1** instead of 'IN' and 'OUT'. This way, your query will be simplified:

```
SELECT
    `ID`,
    `QTY`,
    SUM(`TYPE`) AS SUM_TYPE_NUMERIC,
    MIN(`DATE`) AS first_DATE,
    COUNT(*) AS count_rows
FROM `SALES_TABLE`
GROUP BY `ID`, `QTY`
```

**B- Add a field `TYPE_NUMERIC`** with -1 AND 1 values (assign this values to every register depending of its `TYPE` value). Finally, our query will be:

```
SELECT
    `ID`,
    `QTY`,
    SUM(`TYPE_NUMERIC`) AS SUM_TYPE_NUMERIC,
    MIN(`DATE`) AS first_DATE,
    COUNT(*) AS count_rows
FROM `SALES_TABLE`
GROUP BY `ID`, `QTY`
```

**C- Add a table `TYPES`** with fields `TYPE` AND `TYPE_NUMERIC`, it will contain two registers: ('IN', -1) and ('OUT', 1). This is a normalization of B alternative. That way, you can use that table and `TYPE_NUMERIC` values in your query:

```
SELECT
    s.`ID`,
    s.`QTY`,
    SUM(t.`TYPE_NUMERIC`) AS SUM_TYPE_NUMERIC,
    MIN(s.`DATE`) AS first_DATE,
    COUNT(*) AS count_rows
FROM `SALES_TABLE` s
JOIN `TYPES` t ON t.`TYPE` = s.`TYPE`
GROUP BY s.`ID`, s.`QTY`
```

Comment: Hi Jose, thank you for the answer. However it caught error:`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.`

Comment: Are you using MySql? IF() is available in MySql but maybe not in your database engine. Maybe you need a numeric field to make the SUM(), I don't know if is can maked it using CASE.

Comment: Hi Jose, no I'm using SQL.

Comment: @nilsinelabore I edited my answer adding alternatives.